# Run command via python with sudo and capture stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo

I want to run a sudo command from within python, because my script does a lot of things, that should be handled without the right necessary for commands like `apt install`.

Further for most of those command I need the return value for analysis.

What I have so far:

```py
def _logable_sudo(self, cmds: List[str], password: str):
        sudo_cmds = ["sudo"]
        sudo_cmds.extend(cmds)
        process = Popen(sudo_cmds, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
        process.communicate(f"{password}\n".encode())
        with process.stdout:
            try:
                for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
                    # TODO replace print with actuall logging
                    print(line.decode("utf-8").strip())

            except CalledProcessError as e:
                print(f"{str(e)}")
```

I tested this without the `stdin=PIPE` for normal command and without the `communicate` and it worked. But achieving similar and parsing pw to the sudo command failed.

I've also tried with `["echo", f"{password}\n", "|", "sudo", "-S"]`, but this always returns the command in the print line instead of executing the command.

Comment: Many programs that read a password don't read it from standard input, they read from the terminal. Use `pexpect` to automate interactive applications that require a terminal.

Comment: @Barmar, ...the `-S` _explicitly_ tells sudo to accept a password on stdin.

Comment: @MaKaNu, take out the `echo` and write your process's stdin direct from Python. That is, `process.stdin.write(...)`. (You can't use both `communicate()` and then explicit reads from `process.stdout`; it's one or the other -- if you _are_ using `communicate()`, you should store its return value, which will include both stdout and stderr from your process; _because_ communicate reads both those, they're not available for you to read explicitly in your own code later)

Comment: you can't use `"|"` in the argument list. That's shell syntax, but when you give a list to `Popen()` it doesn't use the shell.

Comment: If you want to pipe two commands together, run two `Popen()` calls. Use the `stdout` pipe of the first as the `stdin` of the second.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Their first code snippet doesn't use `-S`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've looked into your approach, but having issues to achieve the wanted. For the command: `cmd = ["sudo", "-S", "ls"]`, for the process: `process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)`. This resulted in a password prompt. So I created the oneliner `process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE); process.stdin.write("f{password}\n".encode()); val = process.communicate()`. This resulted in failed password input

Comment: @MaKaNu, communicate **or** write, not both. And you need to use stdin=POPEN either way. The documentation spells all this out if you bother to read it.

Comment: I've bothered the documentation and the section about communicate is not very clear in this context. I've also tried with only communicate and the sudo prompt returns "please try again", I am not sure what you state with `stdin=POPEN`.